# Algorithmic representation of list of list

Tags: algorithm, list, representation

I am creating a list with the elements of another list. I want to make sure about two things. First that the list is made from another list and second the size of list changes. Is the following representation good enough ?

```
n ∈ {2,3,4}
new_list = [list[1], ... , list[n]]
```

How can I represent algorithmically that I create the "new_list" with elements of "list" without the dots ?

Comment: "Good enough" - it is so subjective.  Anything (pseudo-code) a person can understand is good enough for that person.   If you are not sure, or want to increase readability, just write a comment.   Don't worry too much about notation (except you want to publish into a journal/book).  It is for usage, and it is not a law, is it?  :)

Comment: I want to publish into an article and I was wondering the most clear way to represent such list. If it is pseudo code, I thing it's understandable but will it be different in algorithmic representation, I was not sure. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard of pseudo-code.  (I am glad there isn't.)

- [Standards for pseudo code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301756/standards-for-pseudo-code)
- https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42226/the-convention-for-declaring-arrays-in-pseudocode

Therefore, I think it is vastly up to you to imagine what is good/bad.

Here are some rough conventions, but none address what you asked directly  :-

- http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr11/cos116/handouts/Pseudocode_Reference.pdf
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/304088-question-in-declaring-and-using-arrays-in-writing-pseudocode/
- http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs016/static/files/docs/PseudocodeStandards.pdf

Therefore, I will use my opinion : the pseudo-code you show looks OK for me.
  Just be sure that your article uses **consistent** notation.
(use same symbol/pattern to denote the same thing)

I hope that this solution is *good enough* for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.